# How to remove hanging start up application (windows mobile)?

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6.5

I am developing a native application for Windows Mobile 6.5 (Samsung Omnia II i8000). After making some changes, my application hangs when it is run.

The problem is my application is also run during Start Up (via \windows\startup shortcut) and whenever I restart the phone, it'll always run my application and hangs there. ActiveSync is not connected yet (I'm using WinXP,VS2005), so I cant use `pdel` from itsutils.

Anyone has any Idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Hard Reset(Factory Defaults) the device by using Key the following procedure:

**Hard Reset of Omnia 2**

1. First switch off your phone
2. Next hold Volumn Up + Screen Lock
3. Then hold Green and Power Button together
4. Then press Answer Call (left) button to confirm hard reset

You must hold the Volume Up + Screen Lock + Green + Power together and hold onto it. Release all once you see the Hard Format Screen.

Master Reset of Omnia by DialPad
You can also key in the following code to the dial pad to do a Master Reset
*2767*3855#

Comment: Thanks! It works. Btw, there is no Green button in my phone, so I used Answer button.

Comment: Warning: The first method (Hard Reset) will not clear 'My Storage' while the second method (Master Reset) will clear 'My Storage'

Answer (score 1):

At last you can flash your phone with the new ROM (leaving your 8GB storage intact) using Octans Downloader.
[Guide to flashing ROM on I8000](http://www.modaco.com/content/i8000-omnia-ii-gsm-rom-discussion/297627/guide-to-flashing-rom-on-i8000/)